# XSL function calls in Apache FOP are not working

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

Using the following in our Apache FOP v2.2 server will fail in generating the PDF. I've downloaded the FOP 2.2 binary to debug locally and have the following proof of concept inputs. When I remove the call `my:foobar()`, there are no issues. FOP 2.9 also fails, although with a little bit different error message.

Why can't I call xsl:function's?

XSLT - `transform.xsl`

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="http://example.com/namespace"
    extension-element-prefixes="my">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="my:numberFromMm" as="xs:string">
        Foobar
    </xsl:function> 
    
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-portrait" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin="2cm">
                    <fo:region-body/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-portrait">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block>
                   Hello, <xsl:value-of select="name"/>! My converted: <xsl:value-of select="my:numberFromMm()" />
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML- `source.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name>Frank</name>
```

Command to generate PDF:

```
fop.bat -xml "C:\PATH\TO\FILES\source.xml" -xsl "C:\PATH\TO\FILES\transform.xslt" -pdf ./output.pdf
```

Output (FOP2.2):

```
Oct 16, 2023 2:29:14 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
INFO: Rendered page #1.
Oct 16, 2023 2:29:14 PM org.apache.fop.cli.Main startFOP
SEVERE: Exception
org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Instance method call to method numberFromMm requires an Object instance as first argument
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Instance method call to method numberFromMm requires an Object instance as first argument
        at org.apache.fop.cli.InputHandler.transformTo(InputHandler.java:296)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.InputHandler.renderTo(InputHandler.java:116)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.startFOP(Main.java:186)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.main(Main.java:217)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Instance method call to method numberFromMm requires an Object instance as first argument
        at org.apache.xalan.extensions.ExtensionHandlerJavaPackage.callFunction(ExtensionHandlerJavaPackage.java:422)
        at org.apache.xalan.extensions.ExtensionHandlerJavaPackage.callFunction(ExtensionHandlerJavaPackage.java:440)
        at org.apache.xalan.extensions.ExtensionsTable.extFunction(ExtensionsTable.java:222)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.extFunction(TransformerImpl.java:475)
        at org.apache.xpath.functions.FuncExtFunction.execute(FuncExtFunction.java:208)
        at org.apache.xpath.Expression.executeCharsToContentHandler(Expression.java:313)
        at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemValueOf.execute(ElemValueOf.java:274)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2402)
        at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:1376)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2402)
        at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:1376)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2402)
        at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:1376)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2402)
        at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:1376)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2402)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.applyTemplateToNode(TransformerImpl.java:2272)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transformNode(TransformerImpl.java:1358)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:711)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1275)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1253)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.InputHandler.transformTo(InputHandler.java:293)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Instance method call to method numberFromMm requires an Object instance as first argument
        at org.apache.xalan.extensions.ExtensionHandlerJavaPackage.callFunction(ExtensionHandlerJavaPackage.java:350)
        ... 24 more
```

Comment: It seems to me that you need to pass in a parameter with the value that you want that function to be formatting, and it's blowing up because you called the function without any parameters.

Comment: Hi @MadsHansen, even though I define a `xsl:param` and call the function with this parameter, the error will still arise and request for a Object. Also, I've tried *not* adding `xsl:param` and simply call the function with a string variable as parameter, still the same error.

Comment: `xsl:function` requires at least XSLT 2.0. Xalan supports only XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet, and the default Apache FOP configuration is invoking Xalan which is XSLT 1.0. You need to persuade it to invoke Saxon. I'm pretty sure there's a way to do that but I've forgotten the detail.

Comment: This seems to make sense. Unfortunately I'm unable to implement Saxon, since our infra-team does not allow it (for shared services reasons). Though this article seems to explain how to implement Saxon. https://steveblamey.co.uk/posts/apache-fop-with-saxon-ubuntu/ 

For now, I've worked around the problem by making my XSLT 1.0 compliant.